# 3D security with Do Direct payment method of paypal

Tags: paypal

I want to know that how can we implement 3D security using do direct payment method of pay pal with US merchant ?.

Can you provide pay pal payment methods which support 3D security using direct credit card processing without using Pay pal account with US merchant account?

Please kindly help on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`3-D Secure` is only for UK.

A US or Canadian merchant can implement 3-D Secure; however, the authentication data is ignored by PayPal. This information only applies to 3-D Secure for UK merchants implementing Direct Payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/ThreeDSecure/