# 3D Security using Paypal for US Merchant account

Tags: paypal

I want to process credit card using pay pal as payment gateway but I do not want to use Pay pal to pay pal money transfer.I want to process direct credit card payments. Also I want to implement 3D security before doing transaction.

How to implement 3D security to process direct credit card payments using pay pal as payment gateway for US merchant?

Please kindly help me !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504433/3d-security-with-do-direct-payment-method-of-paypal/34504693#34504693

Answer (score 0):

From the [Payflow Buyer Authentication Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/buyer-authentication/):

> The Payflow
>   Buyer Authentication service enables you to accept payments that
>   require buyer authentication from cardholders enrolled in the Verified
>   by Visa and MasterCard SecureCode programs.

First you will need to get setup with a Payments Pro Payflow edition account. 
You can either upgrade your existing PayPal account to a [Pro account](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) or you will need to get a test [Payflow Account](https://registration.paypal.com/welcomePage.do?country=US&mode=try).
Once you have a Payments Pro Payflow edition account you will need to get setup with [Fraud Protection Services](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/buyer-authentication/?mark=3D%20Secure#enabling-buyer-authentication) and turn on Buyer Authentication 
Here is the [Developer Guide for Buyer Authentication](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/buyer-authentication/) 
Directly from the Buyer Authentication Developer Guide here is a Sample Request:

```
VENDOR=MerchantUserID&PARTNER=PayPal&USER=UserIDIfAvailOrSameAsVendor&PWD=Pwd4Payflow&TRXTYPE=E&ACCT=5105105105105100&EXPDATE=1216&AMT=19.25&CURRENCY=840
```

Notice that the TRXTYPE=E. That is important because it tells the Payflow server to do a Buyer Authentication.

Here is the link to the full [Sample code for Payflow](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ccpayflow/code.php).
 
Also here is the link to the [Payflow Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/).